# Why is C2H5 a stronger +I group than CH3?

Tags: organic-chemistry, acid-base, amines, inductive-effect

While reading about the basic character of amines, I came across a note which said that $\ce{CH3-CH2-NH2}$ is more stable than $\ce{CH3-NH2}$ as $\ce{C2H5}$ is a stronger +I group than $\ce{CH3}$.

However, according to what I know, isn't $\ce{CH3}$ a stronger +I group as in a longer chain the +I effect dies out?

Comment: C2H5 is stronger than CH3 for the same reason why CH3 is stronger than H. True, the effect should die out along the chain, but _what is it_ that produces the effect in the first place? What is it sitting at the far end of the chain? ***Nothing***. The effect is produced by the chain itself.

Comment: @IvanNeretin Thanks! I guess that works. So C3H7 would be an even stronger +I group?

Comment: Yeah, a little.

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/47020/102629

Comment: @IvanNeretin but why then  methyl has more +I effect than H