# Stability of alkenes

Tags: organic-chemistry, stability, intermolecular-forces, hyperconjugation

The following question was asked on myPAT website:

> [image]
>   [image]

---

I started with the solution by counting the **hyper-conjugative** structures available to each alkene. Based on this concept *only*, order is:

I > II = III > IV

Then, I noticed that II and III have different **carbon count**. As, n-hexane (~68 °C) have more thermodynamic stability than n-pentane (~36 °C), therefore the order becomes:

I > II > III > IV

But, option B was incorrect. What I am doing wrong?

---

The correct option is:

> [image]

Comment: The queston involves heats of formation. Check here: http://ursula.chem.yale.edu/~chem220/chem220js/STUDYAIDS/thermo/heats-formation.html#Alkenes

Comment: @user55119: what should the order be? (acc. to you)

Comment: They only want an answer based on hyperconjugation in which case you have a point. As to heats of formation, II and III should be switched. But the atom count makes a difference.

Comment: You are erroneously associating the boiling point of the substance with its thernodynamic stability. As mentioned by user55119, the heats of formation are a better indicator for stability.

Comment: @TanYongBoon: Okay, I admit that I'm in chaos. I know that lesser the $\ce{\Delta H_f^°}$, greater is the stability. Using this concept and some data from the table (provided by user55119), I can write the stability order based on heat of formation only as: I > II > IV > III. Hence, resultant order comes out as given in option B (as hyperconjugation is more dominant factor). Now what I'm supposed to do with my life?

Comment: @rv7 Ok this question probably doesn't need you to figure out the answer using experimental data. You probably just need to first consider the degree of substitution of the alkene C=C bond and then secondly, in the case of the two di-substituted alkenes, the length of the alkyl groups attached to the C=C bond. The first consideration is, of course, legitimate but the second is slightly dubious, in my opinion. A longer alkyl chain does not actually increase the electron-donating ability of the alkyl chain. But in this case, I suppose the question assumed so.

Comment: See here for the discussion on this topic: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/47008/44877